# How to feed into LSTM with 4 dimensional input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a sequence input in this shape: `(6000, 64, 100, 50)`

The `6000` is just the number of sample sequences. Each sequences is `64` in length.

I plan to fit this input into an LSTM using Keras.

I setup my input this way:

```
input = Input(shape=(64, 100, 50))
```

This gives me an input shape of `(?, 64, 100, 50)`

However, when I put `input` into my LSTM like so:

```
x = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(input)
```

I get this error:

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_37: expected ndim=3, found
>   ndim=4

This would have worked if my input shape was something like `(?, 64, 100)`, but not when I've a 4th dimension.

Does this mean that LSTM can only take an input of 3 dimensional? How can I feed a 4 or even higher dimension input into LSTM using Keras?

Answer (score 6):

you can also consider TimeDistributed(LSTM(...))

```
inp = Input(shape=(64, 100, 50))
x = TimeDistributed(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(inp)

model = Model(inp, x)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.summary()
```

Comment: Exactly the type of layer that I was looking for when I googled my question. I wish that I could upvote more than once!

Comment: For anyone looking for something like this, here's my example use-case: I have been trying to build a model that classifies a call transcript with multiple speakers. The classification happens at the conversation-level not the individual utterance level. I have a transformer model (ala BERT) to but I need to apply it for each utterance in the convo and use it as features. Time distributed layers are perfect for this use case.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is you can't.

The Keras Documentation provides the following information for Recurrent Layer:

**Input shape**

3D tensor with shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`.

In your case you have 64 timesteps where each step is of shape (100, 50). The easiest way to get the model working is to reshape your data to (100*50).

Numpy provides an easy function to do so:

```
X = numpy.zeros((6000, 64, 100, 50), dtype=numpy.uint8)
X = numpy.reshape(X, (6000, 64, 100*50))
```

Wheter this is reasonable or not highly depends on your data.