# 4D input in LSTM layer in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have data with a shape of `(10000, 20, 15, 4)` where `num samples = 10000`, `num series in time = 20`, `height = 15`, `weight = 4`. So I have table `15x4` which is distributed over time. Here is the model I want to train it over this data:

```
...
model.add((LSTM(nums-1,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(20,15,4), activation='relu')))
model.add((LSTM(nums-1,return_sequences=False,input_shape=(20,15,4), activation='tanh')))
model.add(Dense(15,activation='relu'))
...
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, 
found ndim=4
```

How do I define a LSTM layer with 4D input shape?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588937/10375049

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LSTM layer accepts a 3D array as input which has a shape of `(n_sample, n_timesteps, n_features)`. Since the features of each timestep in your data is a `(15,4)` array, you need to first flatten them to a feature vector of length 60 and then pass it to your model:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(10000, 20, -1)

# ...
model.add(LSTM(...,input_shape=(20,15*4), ...)) # modify input_shape accordingly
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Flatten` layer wrapped in a `TimeDistributed` layer **as the first layer** of your model to flatten each timestep:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(input_shape=(15,4))))
```

Further, note that if each timestep (i.e. array `(15, 4)`) is a feature map where there is a local spatial relationship between its elements, say like an image patch, you can also use [`ConvLSTM2D`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d) instead of `LSTM` layer. Otherwise, flattening the timesteps and using LSTM would be fine.

---

**As a side note:** you only need to specify `input_shape` argument on the first layer of the model. Specifying it on other layers would be redundant and will be ignored since their input shape is automatically inferred by Keras.